# Programa pedindo libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Tags: c, c++, dll, codeblocks

Está acontecendo esse erro:

[image: SS]

Estou usando o Code::Blocks, tentando criar um programa com wxWidgets.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Esta DLL é necessária para usar o GCC no Windows e deve acompanhar todas suas aplicações (a não ser que esteja em um caminho que pode ser achado), então copie ela junto com sua aplicação, ou coloque onde tem ela no `PATH`. Ou, não recomendo, mas, coloque junto ao Windows.

Em máquina de desenvolvimento deve bastar estar no diretório do compilador. E já deveria estar lá. Se não está procure por ela. Se não achar, [baixe aqui](http://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll&arch=32bit&version=&dsc=).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu preciso que a dll fique "escondida", ou seja, não quero que fique arquivos além do próprio .exe.

Comment: A pergunta não fala nisto. use `-static-libgcc` para compilar.

Comment: Usei, mas, não adiantou. Já tentei só -static também, as duas juntas e nada.

Comment: Você precisa dar mais detalhes. Programação é detalhe. As coisas podem não funcionar por uma quantidade enorme de motivos. Só dizer que não funcionou não ajuda. Eu considero a pergunta respondida. Se está com outro problema, abra outra pergunta detalhando ele.